# What Delphi coding standards document(s) do you follow?

Tags: delphi, naming-conventions, coding-style

**What Delphi coding standards document(s) do you follow?**

Our company is looking at putting some better coding standards in place, to improve our code’s readability, reviewability, and maintainability.  We’ve come across CodeGear’s “Object Pascal Style Guide”, but it hasn’t been touched in quite a while and I imagine a number of people have made some local improvements or additions.  I’ve come across some published variations and other documents, which I will list, below.

NB: I do *not* want to start a style war.  I just want to know what standards you follow, and why.

Thanks.

---

**UPDATE:**  Well, the "JCL Delphi Language Style Guide" seems to be the clear winner!  Thanks!

Comment: All these formatting "standards" are pointless. No research has been done to demonstrate that one is better than the other... Oh... where are you Wirth?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Project JEDI Delphi Language Style Guide With JCL Additions**

(An extension of CodeGear’s “Object Pascal Style Guide”)

https://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/Project_JEDI_Delphi_Language_Style_Guide

(Thanks to Jeroen Pluimers and AmigoJack for reporting that the old links had died. 
And in case this latest link also dies, [here's its Internet Archive link](http://web.archive.org/web/*/https://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/Project_JEDI_Delphi_Language_Style_Guide), for good measure.)

Comment: Mostly I follow close to this standard.  My exception is that when laying down edit components, I generally prefix them with ed (doesn't matter if its an edit, memo or combo box).  For buttons I prefix with btn.

Comment: The link in the answer does not work any more, but I think this is the article you mean: http://jcl.delphi-jedi.org/documents/styleguide.html, with this as a good additional resource http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org/StyleGuide.htm

Comment: Now it redirects to http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/index.php?title=Style_Guide

Answer (score 5):

**CodeGear’s “Object Pascal Style Guide”**

http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/10280

Answer (score 2):

**Econos – Coding Standard Document**

(Subtitled “Delphi 4 Developer's Guide Coding Standards Document”.)

http://www.econos.de/delphi/cs.html

Comment: Ah, the good old masters Xavier Pacheco,  Steve Teixeira and Stefan Hoffmeister! I kept track of the first two, but wonder what happened to Stefan.

Comment: Link is dead, try: http://box.cs.istu.ru/public/docs/other/_New/Books/Lang/Delphi/Delphi%20Developer's%20Guide/Ebooks/d5dg/chapter6.pdf or http://www.sourceformat.com/coding-standard-delphi-econos.htm

Answer (score 2):

**About.com’s “Delphi Identifier Naming Conventions”**

[http://delphi.about.com/od/standards/l/bldnc.htm (via Wayback Machine)](http://web.archive.org/web/20170124021121/http://delphi.about.com/od/standards/l/bldnc.htm)

Comment: Broken link. Cant find original.

Comment: Thanks, @Peter Rader.  Link changed to use Wayback Machine.

Answer (score 1):

It really doesn't matter as long as you pick one and stick to it. A coding standard is like a dialect, and as long as everyone on the team speaks the same dialect, you're fine.

That said, why not pick the same standard as your runtime library (VCL) and documentation use? Then you will all be speaking the same dialect and you will have an easier time reading the runtime library code. And there are plenty of code examples to illustrate coding conventions.

Comment: That's a very good point, and I appreciate your making it.  Thanks!

That said, we want to pick a standard that tends toward the "complete" side, so the VCL document may not be the best.

Comment: My personal persuasion is that less is more, and at the end of the day, the rules you can capture in a standards document are vastly less important for maintainability than the attitude and experience of the programmer.

Answer (score 1):

There can be a tendency to over-engineer coding standards to the point where they get in the way of writing code.

I agree with Jozz’s comment. You can look at all the recommended standards, pick one and force it upon your coders or you can get your team involved in the process.

In my experience, the best way to get a team engaged is to have the team come up with the idea and the benefits of adoption. Your existing talent is your best resource. Likewise, they can be your ultimate enemy if you force them down a path they don’t buy into.

So, take a look at your existing coding variants and get the team together for some vibrant discussions on:

- The reasons for adopting a coding standard.
- Essential considerations in standardization.
- Surfacing any insecurities in the team surrounding this issue.
- Finding a point of agreement. What's important and what's not.
- Establishing some corporate objectives so everyone feels like they are working towards a common goal.
- Get the team to sell the benefits of standardization to themselves.

The most important objective must be to establish a ‘standard’ that best serves your team and your company.

Answer (score 1):

For some inane historical reason, the coding standard at my work is to have all keywords in uppercase, in both delphi and sql. Thank god for caps lock.

Answer (score -3):

**CodeGear’s “Hungarian peanut butter”, for naming identifiers**

http://dn.codegear.com/article/27983